# URL Shortner by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My current url is

```
http://localhost/ssl_project/gp_crm/home.php?route=user_create
```

But i want to show it as

```
http://localhost/ssl_project/gp_crm/user_create
```

I am using the below code in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /ssl_project/gp_crm/home\.php\?route=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /ssl_project/gp_crm/home/%2/%3?%4 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?ssl_project/gp_crm/home/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /ssl_project/gp_crm/home.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

After use this code I got

> Error 500.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Below rule should work, if it is not conflicting with your other rules, use it in your gp_crm directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/])$ home.php?route=$1 [L]
```